# Find transition matrix for Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, probability-limit-theorems, transition-matrix

The problem is the following: 
An individual has three umbrellas, some at her office, and
some at home. If she is leaving home in the morning (or leaving work at night) and it
is raining, she will take an umbrella, if one is there. Otherwise, she gets wet. Assume
that independent of the past, it rains on each trip with probability 0.2. To formulate
a Markov chain, let  be the number of umbrellas at her current location. 
(a) Find the transition probabilities for this Markov chain.
(b) Calculate the limiting fraction of time she gets wet.
For part a) I have written the following matrix: 
 
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0 & 0.8 & 0.2 & 0 \\ 0.8 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ 
 where the rows and columns represent the number of umbrellas in her particular location (we are transitioning from row i to column j).
Though I think my solution to part a) might be right, I don't know how to approach part b). Can someone give me a hand? I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're saying the states in this Markov Chain are $\{0,1,2,3\}$ where each number represents the number of umbrellas present at a location, right? If so, $p_{00}=1$ means the probability you leave a location with no umbrellas and enter a location with no umbrellas is $100$%. I would double check your transition probabilities.

Comment: I see, I think my interpretation of the transition matrix is not the correct one. I will check again, thank you!

Comment: I just changed the transition matrix. Now my interpretation is that if you're going from a location that has 0 umbrellas, then the other location will have 3 with probability 1. Then going from a location with 1 umbrella to 2 umbrellas occurs with probability 0.8 because it didn't rain, and from 1 umbrella to 3 umbrellas with probability 0.2 since it rained, and you took the only umbrella with you, and so on. Does this make sense now?

Comment: This looks better to me. For $(b)$ do you know how to find a steady state distribution and how to use it to answer the question?

Comment: You mean a vector v such that v=Pv where P is the matrix? If so, how would this tell me the fraction of time she gets wet?

Comment: I think you mean $\pi P=\pi$ where $\pi$ is your stationary row vector. If $$\pi=(\pi_0,\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$$ then $\pi_j\approx \mathbb{P}(X_n=j)$ for large $n$. Given this, do you know which entry of $\pi$ you'll refer to in order to answer $(b)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the notation. I'm not sure if it would be the first or last entry ($\pi _{0} or \pi_{3}$), but I think it is the first since we want the fraction of times where $X_{n}=0$ . Is this correct?

Comment: Almost.  The fraction of times when $\ X_n=0\ $ is the fraction of times the woman begins her trip from a location without an umbrella.  But she will only get wet if it's also raining, which isn't certain to be the case.

Comment: I got it now, thank you so much!